# NAnt, sqlcmd.exe and error codes

Tags: nant, sqlcmd

I can't seem to get NAnt to abort my build when it encounters an error.  Here's one of many *sqlcmd.exe* executions:

```
<property name="test" value=""/>
<exec program="sqlcmd.exe" resultproperty="test" failonerror="true"
      basedir="${sqlcmd.dir}" commandline="${commandline.script}" verbose="true">
   <arg value="${filename}" />
   <arg value="-v databaseName=&quot;${Database.Name}&quot;" />
</exec>
<echo message="Result: ${test}"/>
```

When I hit this step, I end up with an error due to (in this case) a missing comma.  Here's the output:

```
[exec] Starting 'C:\...\sqlcmd.exe (-E -S (local) -e -d "Core"
       -i "C:\...\Associations.sql" -v databaseName="Core")'
       in 'C:\...\Scripts'
[exec] <snip - lots of SQL>
[exec] Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server <snip>, Line 7
[exec] Incorrect syntax near 'CreatedDate'.
[exec] Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Server <snip>, Line 11
[exec] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this
       statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces
       clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
       statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
[echo] Result: 0
```

Pretty nasty error, and yet *sqlcmd.exe* appears to set the return code to 0.

Any ideas to make sure my script aborts when I'm missing a comma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try setting the `-b` option? That will set `ERRORLEVEL` to 1 when an error occurs. Could help Nant decide.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms162773.aspx) seems to state that you need to pass the `-r` switch to send errors to `stderr` which Nant uses to check for errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, passing `-r 1` doesn't seem to change the result of the command.